# DatePicker update value on save button hit, even if there's no change?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a DatePicker binding to a backing variable via a two-way binding. The variable starts as null. I don't want to show the date until a value for it has been set, so I have it set to `Opacity=0` with a button on top of it which triggers the DatePicker which it's clicked.

The issue that I have is that if someone clicks the button, then accepts the current date, it does not update the binding. If possible, I would like for it to update the binding no matter whether the value has changed.

I have tried changing the binding to `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, but to no effect.

The only way that I can see to do this would be to manually parse the visual tree, retrieve the Flyout that the button opens, then hook into its Closed event. The problem with this is that I will have problems in the case the "Cancel" button versus the "Accept" button has been pressed.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? I'm going to try to fix it the way that I have suggested until someone suggests otherwise, as it's the only way that I can see for it right now. I'll update if it works.

Edit: Some code example

My current declaration (minus some formatting) is this:

```
<local:DatePickerCustom Date="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Opacity="{Binding IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegationToOpacityConverter}}"
                        x:Name="DatePicker"/>

<Button Content="Select Date"
        Command="{Binding ElementName=DatePicker, Path=ClickTemplateButtonCommand}"
        Visibility="{Binding IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

So the way it works is that if the `Value` is currently empty, only the Button shows. In the case that it is not empty, then the full DatePicker shows.

The `ClickTemplateButtonCommand` is implemented in my `DatePickerCustom` class which directly inherits from `DatePicker` but adds:

```
public void ClickTemplateButton()
{
    Button btn = (GetTemplateChild("FlyoutButton") as Button);            
    ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(btn);
    IInvokeProvider provider = (peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider);

     provider.Invoke();
}

public RelayCommand ClickTemplateButtonCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(ClickTemplateButton);
    }
}
```

So what I'd like to be able to do is to listen for the `Flyout` closed event and tell if the "Accept" button has been pressed or not.

Edit 2:

It appears that the popup used by the DatePicker is not accessible in the way I was expecting. This way may not be possible.

Comment: would be easier for others to understand or follow if you would post an exact example of the code that you are talking about in question

Comment: I'll add some of my code so far.

Comment: and you could also add some conditional logic to first capture the current Date when the application starts and then check if the Dates are Equal or the same but hard to tell without seeing existing code logic

Comment: The problem that I've found with that is that comparing "IsEmpty" against the current date can cause some issues in the case that a user actually wants to enter the current date as a valid value.

Comment: I think DateChanged event of DatePicker is what you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately that only gets fired when the date actually changes, not any time the Accept button is pressed.